# javascript and onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript"> 
function hello() {
  alert("Hello");
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="hello();">Go </a>
```

This is what I want:

When an user click on "Go", then appear the alert message but the user remains on the same page. With the code above this doesn't work. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the function `return false;` to prevent the link from being followed.

Answer (score 3):

Change to this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="hello(); return false;">Go </a>
```

Or if you're determining the outcome inside the function:

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript"> 
function hello() {
  alert("Hello");
  return false;
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="return(hello());">Go </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript"> 
function hello() {
    alert("Hello");
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="return false; hello();">Go </a>
```

EDIT:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="hello(); return false; ">Go </a>
```

Comment: You need to reverse the order such that `hello()` is before `return false`. As is, it just returns `false` to the event handler and stops executing. [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/EzqQa/).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a div tag with the onclick and style the css from the div that it looks like a link.